# Sorting Columns of type decimal? (nullable) in WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, nullable

I am working with a `DataGrid` in WPF with several `decimal` columns. I recently changed the bound properties to `decimal?`s and now these columns are not able to be sorted by clicking on the header (as my other columns are). However, I can still sort them using methods in my code-behind. Does anybody know if it's possible to sort the `decimal?` columns by clicking the header or what the reason behind it is if it's not possible? Here is my relevant code:

A couple of the columns in question (The attribute attaches to a behavior for the DataGrid. Enabling/disabling the behavior makes no difference):

```
[Column("PPAvg", 7)]
public decimal? ProjectedPointsAvg { get; set; }

[Column("PPHi", 8)]
public decimal? ProjectedPointsHi { get; set; }

[Column("PPLo", 9)]
public decimal? ProjectedPointsLo { get; set; }
```

The DataGrid itself:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="poolDataGrid"
          Grid.Row="1"
          CanUserAddRows="False"
          IsReadOnly="True"
          MouseDoubleClick="poolDataGrid_MouseDoubleClick">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <local:ColumnHeaderBehavior />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</DataGrid>
```

I can still sort via code-behind using something like this:

```
var col = poolDataGrid.Columns.SingleOrDefault(c => c is DataGridTextColumn && c.Header.ToString() == "PPHi");
poolDataGrid.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription(col.SortMemberPath, ListSortDirection.Descending));
```

Unfortunately, I don't have much else to add. If anybody could help me out with this I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sort a DataGrid with nullable property but you need to define all columns on your own. So it should be something like this:

```
<DataGrid Name="poolDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
   <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column1"  Binding="{Binding ProjectedPointsAvg }"/>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column2" Binding="{Binding ProjectedPointsHi }" />
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column3" Binding="{Binding ProjectedPointsLo}" />
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Why does `AutoGenerateColumns` have problems with nullalble properties?

It appears that columns are only auto-generated for properties whose type is a bindable type.

More: http://vaultofthoughts.net/IsBindableTypeMysteryMethod.aspx

Tested on: VS2012 .NET 4.5

Comment: Thanks for the reply. After a bit of thinking I decided to take a different route that avoids using nullables. It is unfortunate that auto-generated columns have this issue but there are always ways around it. Either way, your answer gave me the information I needed so I will certainly accept it.

Answer (score 9):

DataGridColumn.CreateDefaultColumn(ItemPropertyInfo) tests PropertyType for IComparable
and sets CanUserSort to false for nullable types.

To enable standard sorting on autogenerated columns for nullable primitives:

```
void DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    if (!e.Column.CanUserSort)
    {
        Type type = e.PropertyType;
        if (type.IsGenericType && type.IsValueType && typeof(IComparable).IsAssignableFrom(type.GetGenericArguments()[0]))
        {
            // allow nullable primitives to be sorted
            Debug.Assert(type.Name == "Nullable`1");
            e.Column.CanUserSort = true;
        }
    }
}
```

This works (at least) for nullable primitive types.